# Calling (params object[]) with Expression[]

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I'm trying to call String.Format from with in a Linq.Expression tree. Here's a quick example:

```
    var format = Expression.Constant("({0}) {1}");
    var company = Expression.Property(input, membernames.First());
    var project = Expression.Property(input, membernames.Last());
    var args = new Expression[] {format, company, project};
    var invoke = Expression.Call(method,args);
```

The issue however is that String.Format has the signature of:

```
String.Format(string format, params object[] args)
```

and I'm trying to pass in Expression[].

Now I could go through all the trouble of creating an array, populating it with the results of my expressions, but what I really want the result to be, is something like this:

```
String.Format("({0}) {1}", input.foo, input.bar)
```

How do I go about calling a params function via Linq Expressions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What `params` actually does is just to specify [`ParamArrayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.paramarrayattribute.aspx) for that parameter. The C# compiler understands this, and creates the array behind the scenes.

Expressions don't understand this, so you actually have to create the array by yourself, if you want to call a method with `params`. This can be also seen by the fact that when you assign a lambda using `params`-method to an expression, the expression contains the array creation:

```
Expression<Func<string>> expression = () => string.Format("",1,2,3,4);
string expressionString = expression.ToString();
```

Here, `expressionString` will contain this string:

```
() => Format("", new [] {Convert(1), Convert(2), Convert(3), Convert(4)})
```

To create an expression that creates an array, use the [`Expression.NewArrayInit()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336533.aspx).

That being said, if you only want two parameters (or one or three), there is [an overload of `string.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf3d0ccc.aspx) that you can use directly from an expression.

Answer (score 0):

`params` is just syntactic sugar.  Ultimately the parameter is just an array.  Therefore, the parameter type should be `object[]` and an expression describing such an array is what you should pass as the second argument.  In other words, you should only have **two** arguments, not *three*.  And the second argument should be a two-element array containing what is currently your 2nd and 3rd arguments.