# How to pass runtime argument variable in Expression.Call?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, argumentexception

I'm missing something trivial here. Say I have a method like this:

```
abstract class C
{
    public static void M(Type t, params int[] i)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm learning expression trees and I need to build a delegate that calls this method *with some predefined arguments*. The problem is that I don't know to choose the correct overload and pass arguments of `Expression.Call`.

I want to achieve this:

```
//I have other overloads for M, hence I need to specify the type of arugments
var methodInfo = typeof(C).GetMethod("M", new Type[] { typeof(Type), typeof(int[]) });

//this is the first argument to method M, not sure if I have chosen the right expression
var typeArgumentExp = Expression.Parameter(someType);

var intArrayArgumentExp = Enumerable.Repeat(Expression.Constant(0), 3);

var combinedArgumentsExp = new Expression[] { typeArgumentExp }.Concat(intArrayArgumentExp);
var call = Expression.Call(methodInfo, combinedArgumentsExp);
```

At the `Expression.Call` line I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for
>   call to method 'Void M(System.Type, Int32[])'

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like this (shown here [Calling (params object[]) with Expression[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117464/calling-params-object-with-expression)):

```
//I have other overloads for M, hence I need to specify the type of arugments
var methodInfo = typeof(C).GetMethod("M", new Type[] { typeof(Type), typeof(int[]) });

//I fixed this issue where the first argument should be typeof(Type)
var typeArgumentExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type));

var intArrayArgumentExp = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(int), Enumerable.Repeat(Expression.Constant(0), 3));

var combinedArgumentsExp = new Expression[] { typeArgumentExp }.Concat(intArrayArgumentExp);
var call = Expression.Call(methodInfo, combinedArgumentsExp);
```

[Expression.NewArrayInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336533.aspx) does the trick. Thanks hvd for his direction.

Answer (score 4):

The `params` keyword does not do anything at runtime. When you call `C.M(t, 1, 2, 3)`, the compiler transforms this to `C.M(t, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })`. In this case, you are performing parts of the job of the compiler, and this is one transformation that becomes your responsibility. You should explicitly create the array, and call `C.M` with exactly two arguments.

Comment: Thanks your answer gave me the right direction